# Sorted lists in C++

Tags: c++, list, data-structures

I am studying data structure course and have been asked to create a sorted list, however I get an error whenever trying to declare a variable that use datatype. 
Here is what I have done so far

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;
int main(){
  List<int> x;
  // Other Code for testing
}
const int MAX_ITEMS = 30;
template<class T>
class List{
private:
  int size;
  int currIndex;
  T data[MAX_ITEMS];
public:
    // list functions
};
```

However when compiling this I get an error:

```
$ g++ sortedList.cpp
sortedList.cpp:5:3: error: use of undeclared identifier 'List'
  List<int> x;
  ^
sortedList.cpp:5:11: error: expected '(' for function-style cast or type
      construction
  List<int> x;
```

The error is with this line `List<int> x;`, isn't that how we are supposed to declare variables with templates?

Full code can be found here: https://pastebin.com/T2hXDxAP

Comment: Move `main()` to the bottom.

Comment: C++ requires forward-declarations. Move your `List` definition to above `main`, ideally in its own header file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you were the compiler. You are reading the file from the top down, and you encounter this:

```
List<int> x;
```

When the compiler sees this, it goes:

> WTF! I've never seen that before. Is it an identifier? Let me check... Nope! Nothing before `main` or in `main`! Random gibberish? Yes, let's create an error!

So the compiler creates an error. To fix this, you need to define the class before `main`. (You cannot forward declare the class as it is a template, which needs to be defined before it is used More info can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)).

Comment: Nice explanation .. Thanks!